# How can I change data in ngTable without calling getData?

Tags: angularjs, api, ngtable

I need to change data on-the-fly with an `ngTable` without asking the data to the service API.

Suppose I have this call when I route in the controller:

```
vm.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
    count: 5
}, {
    counts: counts,
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'
    },
    getData: function(params) {
        return ApiService.query({
            limit: params.count(),
            offset: (params.page() - 1) * params.count(),
            sort: params.orderBy()
        }).$promise.then(function(response) {
            params.total(response.totals);
            return response.items;
        });
    }
});
```

With this `ngTable` creates the table perfectly with right pagination and everything works fine, I can navigate pages, change pagesize, sorting, ecc..

**Now suppose I have a broadcast message arriving each 5 seconds giving me an object with the data for a row in the table, and I want to change that row *and only that* with the new data.**

If I do what you see below `ngTable` calls `getData()` and the entire rows table refresh.

That seems to me illogic because if I pass the data via `dataset` you shouldn't call `getData` again, don't you think?

Or am I missing something?

```
$scope.$on('broacastMessage', function(event, data) {
    vm.update = false;
    if (vm.tableParams && vm.tableParams.data) {
        // Check if the new data is in the rows table and remap it
        var newdata = _.map(vm.tableParams.data, function(item) {
            if (data._id && data._id === item._id) {
                item = data;
                vm.update = true;
            }
            return item;
        });

        // Assign new data to the table
        if (vm.update) {
            // Here this method calls getData()
            vm.tableParams.settings({
                dataset: newdata
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Or can I pass the new row in another way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ngTable`, but your code to replace `dataset` with a brand new array (i.e. `newdata`) on each new message is a reference reassignment, which is probably triggering `getData()` by design. Instead, why don't you do your update directly to the existing `dataset` array reference (i.e. `vm.tableParams.data.settings().dataset`)?